# How do I cancel this axios request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, axios

I'm getting a memory leak when my browser is redirected away from this component. So I need to cancel it, but for some reason my cancel token isn't having any effect, and I'm wondering why.

Please take a look, below is my code:

```
  const getBoards = async (**cancelToken**) => {
    try {
      if (localStorage.getItem("token") == null) {
        throw new Error();
      }

      const response = await Axios.get("/boards", config, **{ cancelToken }**);
      setBoards(response.data);
    } catch (e) {}
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    **const request = Axios.CancelToken.source();**
    getBoards(request);
    return () => {
      **request.cancel();**
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: *"I'm getting a memory leak when my browser is redirected away from this component."* That's extraordinarily unlikely.

Comment: Hah! Well here's the message I'm trying to get rid of:
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

Comment: The error message has a *bit* of hyperbole. It's not necessarily a memory leak. But it does mean you're trying to update state on an unmounted component, and you're quite right to be trying to cancel the request to avoid that. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You use the token via the `.token` property, you don't pass the entire object from `source()` as the token. From [the documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation):

> ```
> const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
> const source = CancelToken.source();
>
> axios.get('/user/12345', {
>   cancelToken: source.token
> }).catch(function (thrown) {
>   if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) {
>     console.log('Request canceled', thrown.message);
>   } else {
>     // handle error
>   }
> });
>
> axios.post('/user/12345', {
>   name: 'new name'
> }, {
>   cancelToken: source.token
> })
>
> // cancel the request (the message parameter is optional)
> source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.');
> ```

So translating that to your code,

```
getBoards(request);
```

would be

```
getBoards(request.token);
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^
```

Comment: I've just tried that... Doesn't seem to make any difference :/